# Is there a register_strftime_function?

Tags: c, printf, strftime

Long ago I wrote a variant of `strftime` with added conversion specifications (https://www.gdargaud.net/Hack/SourceCode.html#StrfTime).

Some time ago I discovered that you can add your own conversion specifiers to `printf` with `register_printf_function` (https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html) so I wanted to update my old code with this mechanism, but something similar does not seem to be available for strftime functions. Did I miss it ? Or why isn't it available ?

Comment: You are missing `register_printf_function()`? It is an extension to C. You probably need to pass `-DGNU_SOURCE` when compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `register_printf_function` is a GNU extension that allows for registering custom `printf` format specifiers. Currently the glibc `strftime` function [implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/time/strftime.c) and [implementation](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/time/strftime_l.c) doesn't allow registering custom format specifiers. The function just [ignores bad format specification](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/time/strftime_l.c#L1417) whereas [printf checks](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/vfprintf.c#L1874) the array with custom registered formatting specifiers.